# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when nslog this magic string

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, nslog

I stumbled across that when I used `NSLOG` to print a string of URLs, I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash. Then I know that if the string contains a percent sign `%`, I need to write

```
NSLog("%@", urlStr)
```

to avoid it truns into something weird. But I am really curious why such a string will cause such an effect . So I removed all characters that didn't cause a crash, by this far I was left with this string“

```
NSLog("%3A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%3F%3D%2k%3D%2s%3D")
```

So the question is: Why nslog this string will cause a crush, what happened? I decoded this string and the result is

```
://///?=%2k=%2s=
```

that does't explain at all.
What I used is Swift by the way, does it matters?

Comment: The first argument is the *format string,* it specifies what kind of arguments follow and how they should be formatted. Both `%3A` and `%2F` expect a double argument in the variable argument list. Since you don't provide any arguments except the format string, the behavior is *undefined.*

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for fixed the typo. A solid explanation, but why does `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` be caused by only giving the format string without providing arguments? And when I delete any one of `%2F`, this string no longer causes a crash, but prints out a string like memory addresses. I wonder, what exactly are those percent signs being translated into?